# JSR223 Pre Processor code should run for only HTTP Sampler

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I have a **JSR223 Preprocessor** code given below:

```
String method = sampler.getMethod();
```

JMeter Test Plan given below:

```
      - JSR223 Pre Processor
      - HTTP Sampler
      - JSR223 Sampler / Any other sampler apart from HTTP
```

As **JSR223 PreProcessor** will apply to all the Samplers in the hierarchy, it gives below error for all the Samplers apart from **HTTP Sampler**.

> 2022-05-18 17:32:43,668 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in
> JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor            javax.script.ScriptException:
> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.getMethod() is
> applicable for argument types: () values: []
> at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)
> ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
> at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71)
> ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
> at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89) ~[java.scripting:?]
> at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
> at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:45)
> [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:965)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:549)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]          Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.getMethod() is
> applicable for argument types: () values: []
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
> ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
> ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$getMethod.call(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]
> at Script1366.run(Script1366.groovy:1) ~[?:?]
> at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)
> ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
> ... 9 more

I want my **JSR223** code to run only for  **HTTP Sampler**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if HTTP Sampler before:

```
if (sampler instanceof org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase) { 
   String method = sampler.getMethod(); 
}
```

Similar code in [JMeter](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/c7279348335b820c35ee570462cb2e0b4eb1c370/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/gui/HTTPFileArgsPanel.java#L158)

> ```
> if (testElement instanceof HTTPSamplerBase) {
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) for this clean code, works for me. One question, how do you know about it? From where I can also learn. Accepting it as an answer.

Comment: @SAIR added link ro relevant JMeter code https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/c7279348335b820c35ee570462cb2e0b4eb1c370/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/gui/HTTPFileArgsPanel.java#L158

Answer (score 0):

How about moving JSR223 Pre Processor to be a child of the HTTP Request sampler?

[image]

In this case its scope will be limited to the parent sampler only and it will not be executed before every sampler.

More information:

- [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
- [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri for the answer and suggestion, I thought about it, but I have many HTTP Requests and other Sampler in the script ~100 Requests, if I put this preprocessor as a child then there will be lot of duplication. Should i keep it as it? Or should I create a child of each sampler?